# When am sign in to Chrome with another laptop

Tags: google-chrome

When I am signing in to Chrome with another laptop then all the bookmarks, tabs, history and other browser settings are saved and synced to your Google Account. After sign out of Chrome and disconnect your Google Account but bookmarks are showing in my 2 laptop.

How to remove all my bookmark in the 2 laptop? Kindly share how to resolved this?

Comment: What's your OS?

Answer (score 0):

In google chrome, go to top right corner> Settings > Advanced sync settings. Uncheck bookmarks and all other things which you dont want to get synced. You're done. If you want to delete those bookmarks, go to bookmark manager and select all bookmarks which you want to remove and press delete. You can go to bookmark manager by right clicking on the bookmark bar.

Make sure you do this after signing out of google, otherwise they will get deleted from your account rather than the machine.

Comment: OP asked how to remove bookmarks after signing out, not how to disable bookmark sync.

Comment: Go to bookmark manager. select all (ctrl+A) bookmarks and press delete.

Comment: Please fix your answer then. Use the *Edit* button.